# Regular expression to restrict the length and pattern of currency

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I want to restrict user from entering invalid amount in primefaces input text. Maximum integer and Fraction digits length is known at runtime. I am tring to achive this using JavaScript regular expression.

```
    var pattern =/^\d{0,3}?[\.]?\d{1,3}$/;
    if (pattern.test(amount)) {
        return true;
    }else {
        console.log('rgx Failed');
        return false;
    }
```

For this example I am considering 3 as max integer and fraction length.
Integer part can be of length 0 to 3, fractional part should be atleast one digit and max 3.
But the above mentioned javascript is not working, it is allowing 7 digits in integer part.

I am invoking this script with inputText onKeyDown event, so that I can check for each key press and restrict to enter only valid amount.

Valid Amount's  : 123.123, 12.1, 1.12, .123, 1.3, .1234 etc
Invalid Amount's : 123. , 1234  etc

Comment: You have forgotten the ending delimiter in the regex, causing syntax error.

Comment: I restate my requirement: user can enter only integer part, in which case, decimal and zero after decimal should automatically appear. User may also enter decimal part only, by keying decimal followed by some decimal digits (say .34) , in which case, 0.34 should appear automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used primefaces-extensions inputNumber component, which satisfies all my requirements and conditions.

maxValue=9999.999"/>

Inputnumber accepts, 4digits at integer part and 3digits at decimal part. Formating and appending zeros are handled by the component itself.

Answer (score 2):

A quick solution would be:

```
/^\d{0,3}\.\d{1,3}$/
```

To match the updated requirements:

```
pattern.replace(/^(\d{0,3})\.?(\d{0,3})$/, function(m, g1,g2) {
    return (g1 || 0) + '.' + (g2 || 0);
})
```

will work as long as the input is limited to 6 digits and an optional decimal place

Comment: I guess it will fail for .1234

Comment: With this regular expression I am able to enter only one number in integer part.

Comment: I restate my requirement: user can enter only integer part, in which case, decimal and zero after decimal should automatically appear. User may also enter decimal part only, by keying decimal followed by some decimal digits (say .34) , in which case, 0.34 should appear automatically

Comment: In which case, how does a user enter 1.3?

Comment: User can enter 1.3 or 1(.0 should be automatically added) or .3(0 should be added before decimal point automatically).

Comment: @Sandeep ok, so you want to do more than just match a valid value. You also want to clean up the input. Answer updated.

Comment: It is allowing me to enter 1234567 in integer part and then regx failed.

Comment: Are you just trying to format currency? If so, why not use http://josscrowcroft.github.com/accounting.js/

Answer (score 0):

What about:

`/^(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})|(\.\d{1,3})|(\d{1,3})$/`

It's not clean, but it works.

Comment: After using the above mentioned regx, it is accepting any number of digits in integer and fractional part.

Answer (score 0):

try this....(^\d{1,3}([.]\d{1,3})?)$|(^\d{0,3}$)

better one would be using lookahead ?= or negative lookahead ?!

Thanks

Comment: After using the above mentioned regx, it is accepting any number of digits in integer and fractional part.

Comment: but i dont find any difference.

Comment: I tried your solution. It works fine at http://regexpal.com/. In my application, it is accepting 4 digits in integer part. And also after 3 digits if decimal is given, no decimal part is allowed  to be enter. I am using google chrome